# I am unable to call the json from the json file

Tags: python

This is my json file
`json1.json`

```
[

{"host" : "192.168.0.25", "username":"server2", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"},
{"host" : "192.168.0.26", "username":"server3", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"},
{"remotes": ["/home/server2/Desktop/backupdestination/", "/home/server3/Desktop/backupdestination/"]}
]
```

I am unable to call the remotes from the json file in my python script , i tried doing this but got error

```
json_file = open('/path/to/file') 
destinations = json.load(json_file)
remotes = destinations['remotes']
json_file.close()
for destination in remotes:
    destination += f'/{year}/{month}/{date}'
```

Comment: Your JSON file contains a *list*, not a dict. Inside the list there’s one dict with a key “remotes”, which you would need to find by iterating the list.

Comment: @deceze , How can i do that , Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this:

```
for dicts in destinations:
    if 'remotes' in dicts:
        remotes = dicts['remotes']
```

before your final loop to locate the dictionary with 'remotes' key in the array of dictionaries.

Comment: I am getting this error . `
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git.py", line 118, in <module>
    remotes = destinations['remotes']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
`

Comment: @Nova delete that line and replace it with the code I posted.

Comment: I did as you said , but i am getting this now `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git.py", line 126, in <module>
    path_to_key=x['path']
KeyError: 'path'`

Comment: @Nova that line is not in the code you have posted here. There is no way to tell what the problem is from the error alone. This looks to be a separate problem all together, so please ask an appropriate question and show the relevant code!

Comment: `    `with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      for x in data:
        path_to_key=x['path']`
This is the code

Comment: @Nova you shouldn't do this on SO - you are not suppose to ask a new question in the comments. Assuming your JSON structure did not change, this code is again wrong. But I can't properly post a solution in a comment. Please open properly a new question, and pleas read all the comments on your main post and do it right!

Answer (score 0):

```
json_file = open('/path/to/file') 
destinations = json.load(json_file)
remotes = destinations['remotes']
json_file.close()
for destination in remotes:
    destination += f'/{year}/{month}/{date}'
```

There are quite a few things wrong here.

1. You should start using context managers (with statement) which handles file closing even in the case of an Exception!
2. You are trying to add on to your element in your iteration.

   ```
   for destination in remotes:
       destination += xyz
   ```

Destination is a variable which is newly created each **next**, thus any changes made to it will be overwritten.

1. Where do you get your year/month/date from? It’s unclear in this example.
2. What error does Python throw?
3. What are you trying to do in general?

Comment: Lets ignore  year/month/date
The error is `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "git.py", line 118, in <module>     remotes = destinations['remotes'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
I am trying to load the json file in my python script

Comment: Your problem is right there! 
Your json file is not a dict but a list containing dictionaries.